# How can I add or replace a Google Slide notes text with a hyperlink?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I need to have a note created with Google Apps Script in a presentation on slide 0 where it is having a hyperlink, which I grab off a Google Sheet, attached to it. It needs to be a note not a text or image in a slide. Reason being, that URL's are only "clickable" in a slide if the presentation is put into presentation mode first.

If I do it manually, I can create a notes text, select it and attach a hyperlink. The text changes to a regular hyperlink appearance, which one can click without first of all going to presentation mode.

This is how far I came for now:

```
slides[0].getNotesPage().getSpeakerNotesShape().getText().setText("juhu");
```

But how to add the hyperlink, in this example to the string "juhu"?

If I am trying to get it done with: `.setLinkUrl()` it tells me:

> Exception: The operation is not allowed on notes page element (g7185420b90_2_454). (line 19, file "Code")

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of your requirements:

- You want to put the text with the hyperlink to the note page on Google Slides.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this answer, [Slides service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides) is used.

#### Modification points:

- `setLinkUrl()` is the method of Class TextStyle.

  - From your question, when `slides[0].getNotesPage().getSpeakerNotesShape().setLinkUrl(url)` is run, such error occurs. I think that the reason of your issue might be this.
- In order to set the hyperlink to the text, at first, please use `getTextStyle()` to the object of TextRange. This method returns the object of TextStyle.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

```
var text = "juhu";
var url = "###";  // Please set the URL.

var slides = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides();
var text = slides[0].getNotesPage().getSpeakerNotesShape().getText().setText(text);
text.getTextStyle().setLinkUrl(url);
```

or

```
var text = "juhu";
var url = "###";  // Please set the URL.

var slides = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides();
slides[0].getNotesPage().getSpeakerNotesShape().getText().setText(text).getTextStyle().setLinkUrl(url);
```

#### References:

- [Class TextRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range)
- [getTextStyle()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range#getTextStyle())
- [setLinkUrl(url) of Class TextStyle](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-style#setlinkurlurl)

Comment: @Thomas Holst Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn on [Advanced Slides Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/slides), then use next code to set slide's notes link:

```
let presentationId = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getId();
let presentation = Slides.Presentations.get(presentationId);

let slidesReqs = [];

slidesReqs.push({
  updateTextStyle: {
    objectId: presentation.slides[0].slideProperties.notesPage.notesProperties.speakerNotesObjectId,
    style: {
      link: {
        url: 'https://example.com'
      }
    },
    textRange: {
      type: 'ALL'
    },
    fields: 'link'
  }
});

Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({'requests': slidesReqs}, presentationId);
```

Result:

[image]